# Finding inverse group elements and roots of group elements

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to understand a tiny detail in a proof I'm reading.

Let $\mathbb G$ be a group of prime order $p$ with generator $g$. Let $a,b\in \mathbb Z_p$. We only know $g$ and $a$ (and we can thus calculate $g^a$). Now we are given $g^{a+b}$, at some point in the proof they calculate $g^b=g^{a+b}/g^{a}$. I assume this must be done by finding the invere of $g^a$, and then multiply that with $g^{a+b}$? What algorithm is used for this? The proof relies on this being done in polynomial time.

Also, this makes me wonder, assuming we have $g^{bc}$ with $c \in \mathbb Z_p$, and we know $c$, is there then a fast way to calculate $g^b=\sqrt[c]{g^{cb}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find $g^{-a}$ in polynomial time using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Your second question (when $c = 2$) is *almost* equivalent to the [Quadratic Residousity Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residuosity_problem), which is believed to be computationally difficult, and is the basis for certain crypto-schemes.  The important difference is that this problem is over $\mathbb{Z}_N$, where $N = p_1p_2$ and $p_1,p_2$ are unknown.  Over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ it reduces to [this problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_or_prime_power_modulus), where we can quickly compute the Legendre Symbol (again, specifically for the case $c = 2$).

I can't recall the case of $c > 2$.  Ireland and Rosen's *A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory* discusses solving the equation $x^n\equiv a\mod m$ (where $x$ is the only unknown), which they call the *nth power residues* problem.  This is very similar to yours, but they have the additional information of what $a$ should be.  Regardless, they show that you can decide if $x^n\equiv a\mod m$ is solvable.
When $m = p$, it becomes that this is solvable iff $a^{\frac{p-1}{d}}\equiv 1\mod p$ where $d = \text{gcd}(n, p-1)$.

The above only discusses whether a solution exists, not how to find it.  I'm unsure if there's a poly-time procedure for general $c$, but hopefully the above is useful.